# wordpress multisite image not showing

Tags: wordpress

everyone, I just set my blog multisties, and my .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

but when I upload images, they show redcross on the front of this subsite.

You can visit the image at this url
http://pin.cugala.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/2/files/2012/01/test.jpg

but you cannot read the image at this one
http://pin.cugala.com/files/2012/01/test.jpg
there only 404 returned.

I have read all topics in the wordpress support forum, I Eliminate errors of apache(rewrite module), .htaccess(as you can see above), plug-in(all stoppen), and theme(my theme now is default twenty eleven).

There seems no one could answer it.
I am very very exhausted about this problem.

Is there someone good guy help can help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem, please let me know if https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/14844/125164 works, and what changes did you make?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a lacking htaccess configuration, use the following code for a subdomain multisite subsites to receive the correct uploads path instead of /file path:

```
# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]
```

Here's the full wp-config.php file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```